# Log ASIFormDataRequest body as NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I'm making a multipart request to server using ASIFormDataRequest, and I want to review the post body myself before the request is actually made. Is there any way I can print it to console or something like that?

Comment: offtopic: you should use a "new" ASIHTTPRequest alternative like MKNetwork or AFNetwork: http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that I just needed to

```
#define DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 1
```

After that, the library logs all post body to console (except for binary data, which is truncated).

Answer (score 1):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setStartedBlock:^{
         NSLog(@"setStartedBlock", request.requestHeaders);
}];
...
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The StartedBlock is the very last callback before the connection is actually made to the server.

You can log your entire header using what I posted or if you want just the post data you can use the NSLog james had.

Comment: Completely forgot about these blocks. Thanks, that was useful for retrieving headers. However, it didn't work for post body. I've found the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dataRequest.postData);
```

If you can include some code it would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I can see, ASIFormDataRequest doesn't have a property postData, it has postBody which is of type NSMutableData. Tried reading it from startedBlock as suggested by @endy, but it's nil there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment answers right now so I'll create an answer:

As James Paolantonio said, you can NSLog dataRequest.postData, but only thing you need to do: make this property public by moving code

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *postData;
```

from `ASIFormDataRequest.m` to `ASIFormDataRequest.h`